# Путь для сохранения видео в MediaRecord.setOutputFile() API 29

Tags: java, android

Я создаю приложения для записи экрана. Используя `MediaRecorder`, мне нужно указать его методу `.setOutputFile()` путь для сохранения файла. Раньше я брал путь с помощью метода `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)`, но этот метод устарел в API 29. В документации я нашел, что сейчас для хранения файлов видео, музыки и тд., нужно использовать `MediaStore`, но там я нашел только как добавить уже созданное видео в галерею. Возможно ли как то получить из `MediaStore` путь для сохранения файлов, чтобы он работал в API 29.

Answer (score 0):

Я к сожалению не могу проверить предлагаемый вариант в действии из-за отсутствия устройства Android 10, но теоретически нужно делать следующее: создать файл через [ContentResolver](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#open-file-descriptor) который вам вернет ParcelFileDescriptor, из него вытащите FileDescriptor и вот его уже передаете в MediaRecorder в метод [setOutputFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder#setOutputFile(java.io.FileDescriptor))().